# How to retrieve information about certificate in WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I want to retrieve *Common Name* (CN) property from client certificate in SOAP communication. I'm using Spring **WebServiceTemplate** to create my webservice endpoint. I have already implemented WS mutual authentication following the [example](https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-ws-mutual-authentication-example.html).

Is there any solution to obtain **certificate details** from client request by means of WebServiceTemplate or some other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I have managed to figure it out!
Spring WS provides very convenient way to retrieve the X509Certificate.

Normally, You have an endpoint like this:

```
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

    ...

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
        //method body here
        return response;
    }
}
```

However, Spring allows to add additional parameters the method annotated as **@PayloadRoot**. It can be a **MessageContext** instance.

```
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload MessageContext context, @RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request)`
```

Then You will be able to obtain the `wsse:Security` header as follows:

```
WebServiceMessage webServiceMessageRequest = context.getRequest(); 
SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMessageRequest;
SOAPMessage doc = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
Element elem = WSSecurityUtil.getSecurityHeader(doc.getSOAPPart(), "");
```

Now get the right content of `BinarySecurityToken` tag:

```
String binarySecurityToken = elem.getElementsByTagName("BinarySecurityToken").item(0).getTextContent();
```

At the end, you should recreate the X509Certificate by passing binarySecurityToken as its constructor parameter. Later You can extract CN by many different ways for example by means of LDAP utlis.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

1. Create AbstractSoapInterceptor with this body :

```
    private final static QName SECURITY_QNAME = new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", "");
    private static CertificateFactory certFactory;
    public xxx() throws CertificateException {
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL);
        certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    }
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        SoapHeader header = (SoapHeader) message.getHeader(SECURITY_QNAME);
        Node binarySignatureTag = ((Element) header.getObject()).getFirstChild();
        BinarySecurity token = new X509Security((Element) binarySignatureTag, new BSPEnforcer());
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(token.getToken());
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
    }
```

2. Register it in configuration of endpoint :

```
    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() throws CertificateException {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), xxxPortType());
        endpoint.setServiceName(xxxService().getServiceName());
        endpoint.publish("/xxxx");
        endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new xxx());
        return endpoint;
    }
```